# Grails, UUID, Postgresql, generate views

Tags: java, postgresql, grails, uuid

Im working on a little private project and im struggling with changing the pk to an uuid.
First the software i use:
Grails 2.3.7
java 1.7.0_45
postgresql 9.1
idea 13.0.2

Here is what i did so far:
I created a Domain "TourCategory" with 2 String fields and a String UUID which should become
the pk.

```
class TourCategory {
    String uuid
    String label
    String description

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'uuid', type: 'pg-uuid'
    }

    def beforeValidate() {
        uuid = uuid == null ? UUID.randomUUID().toString() : uuid;
    }

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Then I generated the controller and all the views, but that doesnt work out of the box.
The listpage is fine, but the show, edit isnt working, because grails is trying to create
a new TourCategory rather than to update/edit. so i changed the call in the views from
id to uuid, then at least it finds the correct tourcategoryentry and shows it. if i try to
save the instance it always throws an error:

```
| Error 2014-05-05 14:07:55,053 [http-bio-8080-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - CannotRedirectException occurred when processing request: [PUT] /ProSen1234/tourCategory/update/e0ffda44-4b72-4fca-a0e6-26a2c1b03d6d - parameters:
description: irgendeinbeschreib33
_action_update: Update
label: Schneeschuhlaufen
uuid: e0ffda44-4b72-4fca-a0e6-26a2c1b03d6d
_method: PUT
version: 0
Cannot redirect for object [org.prosen.TourCategory : (unsaved)] it is not a domain or has no identifier. Use an explicit redirect instead . Stacktrace follows:
Message: Cannot redirect for object [org.prosen.TourCategory : (unsaved)] it is not a domain or has no identifier. Use an explicit redirect instead 
    Line | Method
```

I put a println at the begining of each method, and it looks like the parameterInstance is
always (unsaved). I dont understand that, because it seems to be ok and saves the changes
to the db.

in a nutshell:

1. i want to use uuids in a simple domainclass
2. i generated the controller and all the views
3. i changed in all the views the id to uuid

it looks like the instance is sometimes null or at least in a (unsaved) status. i dont
understand that bcause in the show method the instance should be recieved in a clean state.

ps: the entries in the db are inserted by bootsrap.

hope to get some support.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably change your domain with this one:

```
import java.util.UUID

class TourCategory {

    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    String label
    String description

    static mapping = {
        id generator: 'assigned', name: 'uuid'
    }

    static constraints = {
        uuid unique:true, maxSize: 36
    }
}
```

Tell me if it works.